# iOS: implement one-finger pan and two-finger pan gestures?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

The goal is to implement two pan gestures against the same SCNScene: one with one finger and the other with two fingers.

This code below isn't working. The one-finger pan function never gets invoked even though the gesture is assigned a distinct selector. One-finger pans and two-finger pans both invoke `sceneViewPannedTwoFingers`.

From reading other questions it seemed like `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` might be the answer, but these pans are not happening simultaneously. It should be either a one-finger pan or a two-finger pan, never both at once.

Is it possible to have two pan gestures as described above? If so, what's the right way to do this?

```
    // Handle one-finger pans
    let panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(sceneViewPannedOneFinger))
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)

    // Handle two-finger pans
    let twoFingerPanRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(sceneViewPannedTwoFingers))
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(twoFingerPanRecognizer)


func sceneViewPannedTwoFingers(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    print("two finger pan!!!")
}


func sceneViewPannedOneFinger(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    print("one finger pan!!!")
}
```

Comment: Add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate To your view controller and set the gesture recognizers delegate to self inside your view controller and add the shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer method returning true for them

Comment: Try `panRecognizer.delegate = self` before adding it to your scene

Comment: @LeoDabus so you're saying `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` is the solution? then the documentation is slightly confusing as some posts interpreted the function to mean two gestures at the same time. Also please post as a full answer so you can get credit (not that you need the rep :)).

Comment: I have done it in a regular view, so i am not sure if that would work with SceneKit. Sorry I am on my mobile right now so i cant test it with a SceneKit project

Comment: @LeoDabus so it works, but now it's recognizing both at the same time. how do you get it to invoke only the one-finger selector when the user uses one finger and the two-finger selector when the user pans with two fingers?

Comment: You already have two different methods, one for each gesture. Whats not working there?

Comment: @LeoDabus it's invoking both selectors when you pan with one finger. it also invokes both selectors when you pan with two fingers.

Comment: Make sure you set minimum number of touches = 2 to the two finger one

Comment: @LeoDabus of course, so stupid! ugh. though wound up using both minimumNumberOfTouches and maximumNumberOfTouches for each recognizer. any problem with that? also please post as an answer!

Comment: Kkk I can't right now but I will post it later. Happy coding buddy

Comment: @LeoDabus so no issue with using both minimumNumberOfTouches and maximumNumberOfTouches?

Comment: @Crashalot you're fine using minimum and maximum number of touches like this. In fact, with that code, you _might_ not need the delegate...

Comment: No problem at all. Keep the delegate if you need them to work simultaneously

Comment: @jrturton whoa! so much SO rep on this thread. :) is there a performance advantage to not using the delegate? otherwise, is it just better to leave the code as leodebaus described (using both minimumNumberOfTouches and maximumNumberOfTouches)? thanks!

Comment: No performance difference, and I'm not sure without testing if it works without the delegate or not (since the touch requirements for each gesture are incompatible, it shouldn't really _try_ to recognise them simultaneously). The only advantage would be getting rid of code you don't need.

Comment: @LeoDabus don't forget to post an answer so you can get those 10 points :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to your view controller and set the gesture recognizers delegate to self inside your view controller. Add the shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer method returning true for them. Make sure you set minimum and maximum number of touches also for them.

Answer (score 1):

code like this

```
class MyClass : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate --< Delegate
 func gestureRecognizer(_: UIGestureRecognizer,
                           shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
    {
        return true

    }
```

Comment: you have to give delegate to your class to use this delegate method

Comment: this works kinda, but now it's recognizing both at the same time. how do you get it to invoke only the one-finger selector when the user uses one finger and the two-finger selector when the user pans with two fingers?

Comment: when you need it .. use gesture.delegate = self when you dont need it don't use gesture.delegate = self.